# gcc local include path

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang++

I have a directory structure (for a clang++/g++ project) that looks like this:

```
src/
util/
```

In `src/` we find .cc and .h files.  Here we build a library (mylib.a) and our main binaries.

In `util/` we have some .cc files that build utilities that, for various reasons, ought not to be in `src/`.

But this means that files in `util/` have include lines that look like

```
#include "../src/myheader.h"
```

instead of

```
#include "myheader.h"
```

This despite my trying commandline options (to g++) like `-iquote ../src`.

Any suggestions what commandline options to make the second, more simple, include lines work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you run g++ from your top-level project directory, try this:

```
g++ -I./src <... rest of command ...>
```